# Tomstone deletion in couchbase

Tags: couchbase-lite

I have setup the autocomaction in couchbase and purge interval =1 day.
but could see that compacted is running as expected. but could see that tombstone are not deleting from couchbase.

Anyone help on this?

Comment: I think you still have to call `database.compact` to remove revisions older than the max rev tree depth setting. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: What version of Couchbase Lite are you using?

Comment: Roi,i am using sync gateway 1.2 version. jamitz, i have set auto compaction which triggers the meta data purge which will remove the tombstones. older revisions are getting delete from couchbase as part of compaction. but i want to delete the tombstones but meta data purge is not deleting tombstones.